# Generating URLs in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get all the links to the articles (which happen to have the class 'title may-blank' to denote them). I'm trying to figure out why the code below generates a whole bunch of "href=" when I run it, instead of returning with the actual URL. I also get a bunch of random text and links after the failed 25 article URLs (all 'href='), but not sure why that's happening since it should stop after it stop finding the class 'title may-blank'. Can you guys help me find out what's wrong?

```
import urllib2

def get_page(page):

    response = urllib2.urlopen(page)
    html = response.read()
    p = str(html)
    return p

def get_next_target(page):
    start_link = page.find('title may-blank')
    start_quote = page.find('"', start_link + 4)
    end_quote = page.find ('"', start_quote + 1)
    aurl = page[start_quote+1:end_quote] # Gets Article URL
    return aurl, end_quote

def print_all_links(page):
    while True:
        aurl, endpos = get_next_target(page)
        if aurl:
            print("%s" % (aurl))
            print("")
            page = page[endpos:]
        else:
            break

reddit_url = 'http://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews'

print_all_links(get_page(reddit_url))
```

Comment: Why don't you use something like BeautifulSoup (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to scrape the links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rawing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1222951/rawing) is correct, but when I face an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) I prefer to provide the best way to accomplish `X` instead of a way to fix `Y`. You should use an HTML parser like [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse webpages:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

def print_all_links(page):
    html = urllib2.urlopen(page).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    for a in soup.find_all('a', 'title may-blank ', href=True):
        print(a['href'])
```

If you are really allergic to HTML parser, at least use regex (even if you should stick to HTML parsing):

```
import urllib2
import re

def print_all_links(page):
    html = urllib2.urlopen(page).read()
    for href in re.findall(r'<a class="title may-blank " href="(.*?)"', html):
        print(href)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the line

```
start_quote = page.find('"', start_link + 4)
```

doesn't do what you think it does.
start_link is set to the index of "title may-blank". So, if you do a page.find at start_link+4, you actually start searching at "e may-blank".
If you change

```
start_quote = page.find('"', start_link + 4)
```

to

```
start_quote = page.find('"', start_link + len('title may-blank') + 1)
```

it'll work.